# Change template of Drag & Drop module on node add form

Tags: theming, media, nodes

I am using [Drag & Drop Upload](https://www.drupal.org/project/dragndrop_upload) module for multiple images uploading.

But the template I see on node add form (FRONTEND) is this : [image]

And I want to change it to this : [image]

I don't know where can I find the HTML for this template, so I can change it.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Just use css !!

Comment: Thanks @NikhilM , There are actually alot of changes, and I really need to change HTML for this, for example the default is using Tables, I need divs. I am sure that must be possible to change the template.

Comment: I see, changing the filed templates is bit tricky. I would do it with `CSS` which is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by updating css into that module.

Or once try to use [HTML5 Drag & Drop File](https://www.drupal.org/project/dragdropfile) module. Hope this module provided that you want.

> HTML5 drag & drop + HTML5 file upload with XHR2. Allows the user to
>   drag & drop files into a Image/File Field and uploads it immediately
>   behind the scenes. In theory it should work for as many files as the
>   field allows.